# Simplest way to work out structural variant type?

Tags: vcf, genome, variation, structural-variation

In VCF 4.2, a structural variant (SV) can be described with the `BND` keyword in `SVTYPE`. For example, the following example is an insertion (from https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf):

```
#CHROM    POS ID REF ALT                      QUAL FILTER INFO
2 321682  bnd V  T   ]13 : 123456]AGTNNNNNCAT 6    PASS   SVTYPE=BND;MATEID=bnd U
13 123456 bnd U  C   CAGTNNNNNCA[2 : 321682[  6    PASS   SVTYPE=BND;MATEID=bnd V
```

The keyword can be used to describe any SV event.

I would like to work out how to find out if an event is an insertion, deletion, duplication, inversion, etc. The algorithm/program will tell me the example above is an insertion.

I'm not able to find a tool that can do the conversion for me.

**PS:** The program I'm using is GRIDSS. This program would only generate `BND` in the SVTYPE field. It's not strictly a bug (BND can be used for any SV arrangement), but it's annoying in analysis.

Comment: how about 'just' using the `INFO/SVTYPE`attribute ?

Comment: @Pierre SVTYPE is BND.

Comment: @Pierre Some SV programs such as GRIDSS only output BND to the SVTYPE. Otherwise, I would not be here asking.

Comment: from the VCF spec: `INFO=<ID=SVTYPE,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Type of structural variant">
Value should be one of DEL, INS, DUP, INV, CNV, BND.`. So BND (break end) is NOT an INDEL, and NOT an insertion.

Comment: @Pierre My above example took from the specification.

Comment: "Some SV programs such as GRIDSS only output BND to the SVTYPE" oh, I see

Comment: May I suggest you simply not use GRIDSS and instead use a tool that produces valid output?

Comment: @terdon What do you mean? GRIDSS is a published SV program. BND is a valid VCF output?

Comment: If it uses `BND` to indicate an insertion, then it is not following the VCF specs since the `SVTYPE` for insertions should be `INS` and `BND` should only be used for break ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRIDSS's author had posted [his own solution on Github](https://github.com/PapenfussLab/gridss/blob/7b1fedfed32af9e03ed5c6863d368a821a4c699f/example/simple-event-annotation.R#L9). The code is:

```
simpleEventType <- function(gr) {
    return(ifelse(seqnames(gr) != seqnames(partner(gr)), "ITX", # inter-chromosomosal
           ifelse(gr$insLen >= abs(gr$svLen) * 0.7, "INS",
           ifelse(strand(gr) == strand(partner(gr)), "INV",
           ifelse(xor(start(gr) < start(partner(gr)), strand(gr) == "-"), "DEL", "DUP")))))
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer? What's gr? Looks like R, which library should I use for this?